# What is >> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

index is a number. I do not understand what **>>** is in JavaScript.

```
setIndex: function(index) {

    var i = this.index;
    this.index = index >> 0; // ?????

    if (this.index < 0) {
    this.index = 0;

    } else if (this.index >= this.config.items.length) {
    this.index = this.config.items.length - 1;
    }

    return (i !== this.index);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @Quentin Can you explain what use there would be in shifting the value by 0 bits? That's not explained in the question you linked to.

Comment: thanks guys for posting other similar questions, I was not aware of.. thanks

Comment: I suspect what it's actually being used here for is to ensure that index is a number rather than a string. It would be more understandable if it was `this.index = +this.index` though I reckon.

Comment: The intent is `this.index = (int32)index`. `+this.index` doesn't do anything to something that is already a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x >> y` means to shift the bits of `x` by `y` places to the right (`<<` means shift to the left).

[Read more about bitwise operators and see some examples here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)